# JQuery with radio buttons not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am creating a 'my account page as part of a larger project. And I am using jquery to get data about which radio button the user has selected. I cannot figure out why it isnt working, i believe the problem is with the jquery used to dictate when a radio button is clicked.

JQUERY:

```
$("input[name=currentTree]").on('change',function(){
        var currentTreeId = $(this).val();
        alert ('data:' + currentTreeId);
         $.post('selectTree.php',{currentTreeId:currentTreeId} ,function(data,status){

                alert(data + ' is the current tree');

            }); 

    });




       $("input[type=radio][name=currentTree]").change(function(){
        var currentTreeId = $(this).val();
        alert ('data:' + currentTreeId);
         $.post('selectTree.php',{currentTreeId:currentTreeId} ,function(data,status){

                alert(data + ' is the current tree');

            }); 

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
$('input[type=radio][name=currentTree]').change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 'typeA') {
            alert("Got Type A Radio");
        }
        else if ($(this).val() == 'typeB') {
            alert("Got Type B Radio");
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="typea">Type A</label><input id="typea" type="radio" name="currentTree" value="typeA">
<label for="typeb">Type B</label>
<input id="typeb" type="radio" name="currentTree" value="typeB">
```

Comment: No problem, post the current HTML you have after embedding my solution and I'll help you fix it

Comment: I have put it in my question under my previous one

Answer (score -1):

```
$("input[name=currentTree]").on('change', function(){
   ...      
});
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/b80sa4kx/

Comment: Same will also work for click [https://jsfiddle.net/b80sa4kx/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/b80sa4kx/1/). This is not OP issue